# SR-IOV with Qualcomm adapter

Tags: networking, virtualization, ethernet, adapter, lspci

I have a Lenovo laptop with Ubuntu-20.04 installed. The `lspci` command shows the following.

```bsh
lspci | grep Ethernet
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
```

Most examples in search results seem to refer to Intel devices. So, how do I enable SR-IOV for my Ubuntu laptop?

Comment: Do you know for a fact that the adapter in question supports this feature?

Comment: https://blog.scottlowe.org/2009/12/02/what-is-sr-iov/

Comment: I would not expect a laptop to have an ethernet controller capable of SR-IOV.
What problem are you *actually* trying to solve? network connectivity for your VMs can be handled in many ways. SR-IOV is more usually a high performance server technology.

Comment: At the moment, the idea is to split "read-write" traffic.